Center longtable in landscape environment horizontally when viewed in portrait mode
I am unable to center a longtable inside a landscape environment (package pdflscape) horizontally when viewed in portrait mode and when the table spans more than one page.
Note, I have a two-sided document.
I have already tried out the following suggestions but the compilation fails for me: Center longtable horizontally over two pages in landscape
Example LaTex document:
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for landscape environment
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter name}
\section{Section name}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{centering}
% how to center this longtable in the landscape environment?
\begin{longtable}{p{6cm} p{5cm} }

\caption{Example of longtable in landscape environment which 
is not centered horizontally when viewed in portrait mode} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{c}{{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- Continued from the previous page}} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\
\midrule
\endhead
\multicolumn{2}{r}{{Continued on the next page}} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\lipsum[1][1-3] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\lipsum[2][1-3] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\lipsum[3][1-3] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\lipsum[4][1] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\lipsum[1][1] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\lipsum[1][1] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\midrule
% continued on the next page because of longer text
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2][1] \\
\lipsum[1][1] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\lipsum[2][1-3] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\lipsum[3][1-3] & \lipsum[1][1] \\

\end{longtable}
\end{centering}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}

The screenshot shows that the longtable sticks or floats to one side of the page.
But I want to center the table on each page.

Can anybody please help me to center the table on each page horizontally when viewed in portrait mode?

Note that the center of the text area is not necessarily the center of the page.  The showframe option of geometry is useful for this.

If I understand you correctly you want vertical centering (so not \centering, even if that worked with longtable)

\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for landscape environment
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter name}
\section{Section name}

\begin{landscape}

  \ExpandArgs{c}\def{@texttop}{\vfill}
  \ExpandArgs{c}\def{@textbottom}{\vfill}

% centering isn't an environment, and has no effect on longtable \begin{centering}
% how to center this longtable in the landscape environment?
\begin{longtable}{p{6cm} p{5cm} }

\caption{Example of longtable in landscape environment which 
is not centered horizontally when viewed in portrait mode} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{c}{{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- Continued from the previous page}} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\
\midrule
\endhead
\multicolumn{2}{r}{{Continued on the next page}} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\lipsum[1][1-3] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\lipsum[2][1-3] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\lipsum[3][1-3] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\lipsum[4][1] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\lipsum[1][1] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\lipsum[1][1] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\midrule
% continued on the next page because of longer text
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2][1] \\
\lipsum[1][1] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\lipsum[2][1-3] & \lipsum[1][1] \\
\lipsum[3][1-3] & \lipsum[1][1] \\

\end{longtable}
%\end{centering}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}


Thank you very much! Your solution worked for me! :-)
